# Exclude functions from auto-completion

Tags: front-end, packages, customization, autocomplete

Is there a way to exclude a function from auto-completion?  Suppose that you are developing a package, and in the next version a function will be deprecated.  It is better not to auto-complete it so people do not accidentally discover it and start using it, then get hurt when it is finally removed.

Why do I think that this is possible at all?

There are several System-context functions that do not auto-complete. These are either deprecated ones, or perhaps just undocumented ones. One example is `ArgumentCountQ`.

Comment: @Kuba Just to be clear, what I am asking for is not customizing my own installation, but creating a package which does export a function, but disables auto-completion for it.

Comment: That is what I've thought, do you think [tag:customization] does not apply then?

Comment: @Kuba It might apply, I just wanted to make sure the question won't get misinterpreted.